# Authlib token not saved in database

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, authlib

I'm trying to provide an authentication via username and password, which works after hours of hitting my head against a wall.

---

But there is still one thing I can't figure out. I don't get an token inside my database when I issue a token with

```
return authorization.create_token_response()
```

but the token is valid till it timed out. But where is it saved? There is no place I can check what tokens are still valid.

Also I don't get an refresh-token from the endpoint even though I set

```
OAUTH2_REFRESH_TOKEN_GENERATOR = True
```

---

I've used the [authlib example](https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server) to generate my code. But I didn't added the `Implic`, `Client` and `Authorization` grant, as I don't understand them yet.

Any help is appropriated as I really want to understand how Authlib and OAuth2 works.

Comment: This seems not a question that can be answered. But the config key you are using is incorrect. It is `OAUTH2_REFRESH_TOKEN_GENERATOR`. checkout here https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/2/authorization-server.html

Comment: That was just a copy paste mistake of me, sorry.
What would you need @lepture to help me?

Comment: Somehow I managed to find them in the database after an restart of the application. So the only question is, why couldn't I see then at first?
Is is a error of the database (sqlite) or was it just a random appearance?

I will dig into this a bit an post my results here.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that after I restarted my application the tokens appeared in the database.

Unfortunately I somehow had a cached earlier version of my database open and it didn't reloaded the new data so it was there but not on that cached database which I had open.

For anyone having the same problem I can only tell you the following:

- Restart your application
- Check your database twice (maybe check if you have to reload it from disk)

If this doesn't help I can't do anymore for you...